# Welches ist die Ordnung in einen Satz (Akk, Dat, TEKAMOLO)?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case, word-order

I weiss Te(temporal)Ka(kausal)Mo(modal)Lo(lokal), aber mit einem Satz mit Akkusativ und Dativ.

```
A) Ich habe einen Deutschkurs letztes Jahr in der Sprachschule gemacht/gesucht.
B) Ich habe letztes Jahr in der Sprachschule einen Deutschkurs gemacht/gesucht.
C) Ich habe letztes Jahr einen Deutschkurs in der Sprachschule gemacht/gesucht.
D) ...
```

Ein Beispiel mit Akkusativ, Dativ, Temporal, Kausal, Modal, Lokal?

Comment: forget TeKaMoLo... this rule is just wrong! it fully depends on the verb.

Comment: @Emanuel Ich hab', also, basiert auf einer irrtümlichen grammatikalischen Regel alles falsch geschrieben! Wie hängt das vom Verb ab?

Comment: @c.p. there are several forces pulling at the constituents of a sentence. Examples are "alive - not alive" or "old - new". The most important one however is that whatever is that the more relevant an information is for describing what happens, or in other terms, the more a constituent is part or leans toward the predicate itself, the later it comes. Place is very relevant for many verbs that have to o with movement... of course. That's why it sounds so bad to say time after it. Verbs for which time is the defining factor are rare. But for "dauern" you will find time at the end

Comment: cted. because for a duration time is most relevant and defining "Trotz der vielen Kellner (MO) dauert es in diesem Restaurant (LO) immer [ewig, bis die Getränke kommen] (T)." ... and there are billion other examples. The latest Duden Grammatik does acknowledge that fact while several old ones still tried to come up with "rules".

Answer (score 3):

1. All your suggestions are grammatically correct and valid, depending on your emphasis.
2. B) and C) are common versions with slight emphasis on `Deutschkurs` resp. `in der Sprachschule`.
3. A) puts heavy emphasis on `Deutschkurs`. It must be stressed when spoken, otherwise it's confusing.

Answer (score 1):

> Ich habe letztes Jahr einen Deutschkurs in der Sprachschule gemacht/besucht.

Comment: `gemacht` as the OP suggests is totally fine. `bekommen` is not. `besuchen` is bad German.

Comment: @Toscho I would consider *besuchen* a better choice over *machen*, which is in my opinion overly used. *Bekommen* is indeed the wrong word. - I changed the verbs in the answer accordingly.

Comment: Ich kenne keinen Menschen, der `besuchen` sagt. `belegen`, `teilnehmen`, `ablegen`, `durchführen` hab ich alle schon gehört, aber nicht `besuchen`.

Comment: @Toscho Ja, *belegen* finde ich auch OK. *Teilnehmen* kann man auch verwenden, muss man aber natürlich ein *an* einfügen. *Durchführen* klingt eher nach einem Onlinetool. *Ablegen*??? - *Besuchen* wird eigentlich recht häufig verwendet, in Kombination mit einem Deutschkurs hört man es hier in Deutschland logischerweise selten bis gar nicht. Ein typisches Beispiel könnte sein: "Ich habe einen Computerkurs der VHS besucht."

Comment: 'besuchen' is totally fine and acceptable in colloquial and formal speech.